# Android: class not found exception: android.support.v4.app.FragmentPager

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

In my code I
import `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`
but I get a `ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` when I set content view to this xml file:

```
...
 <android.support.v4.app.FragmentPager 
     android:layout_height="0px" 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:layout_weight="1" 
     android:id="@+id/pager"> 
     </android.support.v4.app.FragmentPager>
...
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You have to add compatibility library by right clicking your project and selecting **Android Tools -> Add Compatibility Library**. Once its added, clean your project and build again.

---

[image]

Comment: In my project this resolved issues with missing android.support.v4 library, but I still miss android.support.v13 library!

Answer (score 33):

i'm using `Android Studio Beta 0.8.6` and i had to do it this way

---

**File -> Project Structure**
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Go to `<Your android apk folder>\sdk\extras\android\support\v4` folder and add `android-support-v4.jar` to app library (or whole sdk library).

Answer (score 3):

Add Support library by right clicking your project and selecting Android Tools -> Add Compatibility Library. 
After adding Support Library clean your project and Go to Java Build Path, Go to Order and Export [Last tab] click all currently added Jar files and libraries..press Ok and refresh your Project.. 
It works fine for me..

Answer (score 1):

You should add android.support.v4 jar to your app.

Comment: i have it and i have android-support-v13.jar which contains a support.v4 folder. strang thing i cannot find a ViewPager, in both folders. is that a problem?

Comment: hm...it seams android doesnt contains this class at all

Answer (score 0):

If it is not gradle based then You should Migrate Eclipse ADT based project to Gradle based..
Import Project into android studio..

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem please right click on your project and click Android Tools and now click Support Libraries and then Accept License Now Run your Project It will Work :D

RightClick==>Android Tools==>Support Libraries ==>Accept License