# Why is the ViewPager giving errors in Android Studio Design mode?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-viewpager

I'm using Android Studio 0.8.6 (beta).
 I'm trying to create a fragment using the "android.support.v4.view.ViewPager"

I get the following error when I'm in the design view of the fragment layout:

```
Rendering Problems 

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v4.view.ViewPager (Open Class, Show Exception)

 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  

Exception Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.view.ViewConfigurationCompatFroyo   
at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:148)   
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)   
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)   
at android.support.v4.view.ViewConfigurationCompat$FroyoViewConfigurationVersionImpl.getScaledPagingTouchSlop(ViewConfigurationCompat.java:49)   
at android.support.v4.view.ViewConfigurationCompat.getScaledPagingTouchSlop(ViewConfigurationCompat.java:73)   
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.initViewPager(ViewPager.java:367)   
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.<init>(ViewPager.java:355)   
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:478)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:381)
```

I'm pretty new the Android thing and Android Studio.
 I've been googling and have not found a solution that makes sense to me.
 How do I correct this?

Thanks,
 JohnB

Comment: The design preview only works for simple layouts, you cannot preview something like a `ViewPager` or any other complex `View`. The error message simply means that the `View`,  in your case a `ViewPager`, cannot be displayed in the preview.

Comment: add `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'` in dependencies of `build.gradle` in `app` folder and `sync` gradle. Then `clean project` and `build` it again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

::> Xaver

After several hours of combing through Google, I was able to find the following which helped solve my issue:

[Android: class not found exception: android.support.v4.app.FragmentPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199430/android-class-not-found-exception-android-support-v4-app-fragmentpager)

By adding the missing support library through File->Project Structure, the errors went away.

I CAN in fact view the preview without errors/exceptions.

JB

Comment: Just to clarify the steps.. File->Project Structure. Go to the 'app' under 'Modules'.. Dependencies Tab.... Click +... Library Dependency....support-v4.   The error then disappears after a few seconds while it does its magic

Comment: @Tim I also had to set the scope of the dependency to be `Provided` instead of `Compile`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was the targetSdkVersion in the build.gradle.. as i changed it from 21 to 19, the exception disappeared.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "test.example"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```