# Android Studio ViewPager class could not be found (Rendering Problems)

Tags: android, android-studio

Im following the steps in the android docs here https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging

I use Android studio 1.2.1.1

As soon as i add their code to my XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

i get 
-Rendering problems the following classes could not be found:
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager (Fix Build Path, Create Class)

Tip: Try to build the project.

Ive tried:

Switching between API 21 and 22

Trying Holo Themes

Adding support libraries 4 and 13

heres gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ian.marxbrothers"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:22.0.0'
}
```

Comment: asked to show app.gradle file not output.

Comment: show build.gradle(Module:app)

Comment: okay sorry ive never shown someone my gradle before, i think this is right one now?

Comment: Try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199430/android-class-not-found-exception-android-support-v4-app-fragmentpager/25572380#25572380

Comment: Thats just adding v4? i did that

Comment: Try adding these lines :-  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There actually is no answer.  The Viewpager will not show anything but you can still adjust its size within a layout and then add its contents in xml