# Rendering failed for ViewPager - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

Hello I'm new to Android development. I created a new app with a tabbed activity in it. I had not made any changes to the project. But, when I tried to change the activity with the help of the built-in designer, I got the following error.

The following classes could not be found:
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

[image: Screenshot showing the error]

After a lot of research on google, I found this Stack Overflow article [Android: class not found exception: android.support.v4.app.FragmentPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199430/android-class-not-found-exception-android-support-v4-app-fragmentpager)

It asked to me to add the compatibility library android.support.v4. I added it, and then I was able to build the app successfully without errors. But still I was facing problems with the rendering. The Rendering problems have not been solved.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "aryanware.friendlee"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: post your code@Afrish Khan

Comment: Post your build.gradle